# MITM возможно ли через SSL/TLS

Tags: безопасность, ssl, https, tls

Интересует такой вопрос, возможно ли реализовать mitm (man in the middle) через ssl/tls? Что именно нужно учитывать реализовывая подобное?

Если требуется двухсторонняя аутентификация, то в ходе handshake с сервером, передается 2 сертификата. Если я правильно проинформирован, с помощью этих двух сертификатов можно генерировать свои (так сказать клиентские). поправьте если ошибаюсь. В другом случае, на клиентской части имеется CA.pem файл в котором находится очень много всяких сертификатов. Возможно это можно использовать для создания доверия между мною-сервером и мною-клиентом? Возможно ли расшифровать передаваемый контент в таком случае?

Хочу понять как это работает и защитить свой проект и проверить на уязвимости подобных атак.

Comment: Причем тут языки? И про какую разницу вопрос, между чем и чем?

Comment: язык на котором буду реализовывать. разница между обычным mitm и с использованием ssl

Comment: есть https://mitmproxy.org на Питоне

Comment: @ei-grad 1. вам лучше было задать новый вопрос вместо кардинального редактирования данного вопроса. 2. [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ei-grad если переносите комменты ТС в текст вопроса, то переносите посимвольным копированием, не надо дописывать что-то от себя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, сертификаты передающиеся при установлении соединения или содержащиеся в CA.pem не позволят реализовать MitM-атаку. Сертификат - публичная информация.

Можно выделить два фундаментальных фактора, отвечающих за безопасность SSL/TLS соединения:

1. За аутентификацию стороны отвечает её закрытый ключ. Если злоумышленник получает к нему доступ, то он может выполнять действия от имени субъекта, указанного в сертификате (в котором содержится открытый ключ, соответствующий этому закрытому ключу). В таком случае говорят что ключ и сертификат были скомпрометированы. Субъектом может быть как веб-сервер (тогда в сертификате указывается его домен(ы)), так и клиент (обычно указывается какое-нибудь имя, логин или e-mail), или CA (указывается имя и роль сертификата, полное имя организации и подразделения которое им владеет, страна).
2. SSL/TLS подразумевают наличие доверенной третьей стороны, так называемого Certificate Authority (CA), закрытым ключом которого подписываются другие сертификаты. Соответственно MITM возможен:

   - при компрометации одного из доверенных CA
   - при добавлении злонамеренного CA в список доверенных на клиенте (и на сервере, если используется двусторонняя аутентификация), в том числе если проводится атака с использованием самоподписанного сертификата и пользователь подтвердит возможность его использования

Важным аспектом является надежность используемых алгоритмов шифрования и выбора ключа (вместе называемые Cipher Suite). Устаревшие версии SSL/TLS как правило позволяли использовать ненадежные алгоритмы, либо имели уязвимости в самом протоколе (в том как эти алгоритмы использовались). Важно чтобы сервер и клиент позволяли использовать только актуальные версии TLS и надежные алгоритмы.

Так же, в контексте защиты своего веб-проекта на уровне транспорта, стоит обратить внимание на технологии HSTS (которая помогает запретить работу с сайтом без использования HTTPS) и CSP (позволяет контролировать источники JavsScript-кода, который может выполняться на странице). И изучить типичные уязвимости и технологии защиты от них на других уровнях, начать можно с [OWASP Top Ten](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/) и [OWASP Web Security Testing Guide](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/).

Comment: Требуется двухсторонняя аутентификация. То есть с самоподписанными сетификатами реализация возможна?

Comment: Если речь идет про двустороннюю аутентификацию, то скорее всего имеется ввиду использование самоподписанного CA, которым подписаны клиентский и серверный сертификаты, и они уже в свою очередь не являются самоподписанными. Так что для реализации MITM потребуется либо получить ключ этого CA, либо добавить свой CA в список доверенных на клиенте и сервере.

Comment: На сервере доверить свой сертификат не получится. В ходе handshake с сервером, сервер передает 2 сертификата. Если я правильно проинформирован, с помощью этих двух сертификатов можно генерировать свои (так сказать клиентские). поправьте если ошибаюсь. В другом случае, на клиентской части имеется CA.pem файл в котором находится очень много всяких сертификатов. Возможно это можно использовать для создания доверия между мною-сервером и мною-клиентом? Меня интересует расшифровка передаваемого контента. Использовать это хочу не в кражи чего то.

Comment: Хочу понять как это работает и защитить свой проект и проверить на уязвимости подобных атак.

Comment: @Михаил вы путаетесь во всех понятиях. От этих атак невозможно защититься, нет смысла проверять какой-либо проект.

Comment: @Михаил Что бы сгенерировать клиентский сертификат, которому будет доверять сервер вам нужен закрытый ключ серверного сертификата. Закрытый ключ не передается сервером никуда ни при каких обстоятельствах. Без этого ключа подделка сертификата невозможна

Comment: @Zergatul Просто у меня появилась большая мысль (теоритическая). Атаку трудно остановить, но если знать с чем имеешь дело, можно отбиться а поскольку меня сомнения приследывают последнее время, лучше разобраться где утечка.

Comment: @Mike Я немного запутался, кто то говорит что невозможно, а кто то возможно. Так что остается, если генерировать нельзя, каким образом тогда встать в середину между клиентом и сервером и проецировать через себя весь контент?

Comment: @Михаил Все, кто говорит что можно, сразу указывают что вам нужно что бы соответствующие ваши сертификаты (в данном случае и серверный и клиентский) были подписаны сертификатом, которому стороны доверяют. Так что вопрос только в том, сможете вы такие сертификаты получить или нет. Прописать что то свое в цепочку доверия обоих сторон можно только ели обе стороны осознанно возьмут ваш сертификат и занесут в список доверенных. Либо вам надо умудриться обмануть одного из доверенных центров сертификации что бы вам дали валидный сертификат на выбранное доменное имя.

Comment: @Михаил Если используется клинский сертификат и сервер ожидает, что он должен быть подписан сертификатом, который был создан для данного сервера, то пока вы не достанете этот конкретный сертификат с сервера, вместе с закрытым ключом, вы ничего не сделаете

Comment: @Mike посмотрю что можно сделать. добавьте свой ответ, я отмечу вас так как вы больше всего разъяснили ситуацию.